# Does Eclipse works on El Capitan?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, performance

Official Launch was today. I need to use Eclipse for my classes, and have seen that in Beta 3 update it "broke" Eclipse.

Can anyone confirm to me if Eclipse is running fine on El Capitan?

Comment: I am currently using Eclipse Luna Java 1.7 (my teacher uses it...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Xcode. If you try anything from the command line you will yield:

> $ git status
>   xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

so then you go looking around and you end up at needing to fix a link for command line tools:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

which yields

> xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'

and then you go and reinstall Xcode. Ugh.

Comment: what? he is asking about eclipse, you are talking about xcode what?

Comment: but none of the underlying tools are working, and so I think it breaks apps that depend on them. Java is working fine in 10.11. Open other IDEs and they will show bad behavior as well, because of the underlying break of command line tools.

Comment: You should be fine once you reinstall Xcode. Just extra time.

Comment: I can confirm. Just upgraded to El Capitan, did a fresh Eclipse install (using their new installer - Yay!), and was seeing an Access Resriction banner in eclipse. Ran `xcode-select --install`, restarted eclipse, and everything's fine

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Mars (4.5) runs fine on Mac OS X El Capitan for me.

I am using Java 1.8 update 60.

I also have XCode 7.0.1 installed, but I don't think that is relevant.

Eclipse RCP and SWT apps also work fine.

Comment: @Felipe Probably. I don't think there is likely to be a problem with any release, it was only El Capitan Beta 3 that had an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone gets here through a search engine:

After upgrading to El Capitan, Eclipse gave me the error that it couldn't find a VM at `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin/java`

Reinstalling XCode didn't resolve the problem.  This did:

1. Find java.  I had Oracle's Java SE 7 installed at its default location.
2. Find Eclipse in Finder.
3. Right-click and choose Show Package Contents.
4. Open `Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini` for editing.
5. Change:

   `-vm
   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin/java`

   to:

   `-vm
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

Save, then launch Eclipse as normal.